# Moq simple check if a range has been filled

Tags: unit-testing, moq

Playing around with `moq`, trying to get some test to work. But I'm kind of confused.

I made a really simple interface, with an implementation that holds some collection. There I have 2 methods: `Add`  and `AddRange` (both returning void). What I want to test is:

```
Mock<INoteServiceContext> mockedContext = new Mock<INoteServiceContext>();
var noteServiceImpl = new NoteServiceImpl(mockedContext.Object);

var notes = Enumerable.Repeat(new Note(), 10).ToList();
mockedContext.Setup(m => m.AddRange(notes)).Returns(notes);
var readAll = noteServiceImpl.ReadAll();
```

But `readAll` is `null`, so then I tried:

```
var notes = Enumerable.Repeat(new Note(), 10).ToList();
noteServiceImpl.AddNotes(notes);
var readAll = noteServiceImpl.ReadAll();
```

But still `null`.... What am I missing in this setup?

Comment: Probably setup method is not good because you are providing different list of notes, different object and then setup is never triggered. Probably you want to do something like `mockedContext.Setup(m => m.AddRange(It.IsAny<List<Note>>)).Returns(notes);.`Could you provide also `NoteServiceImpl` to be ablo to localize the problem?

Comment: Hey, indeed my setup was wrong. Didn't quite understand the workflow. Everything is working nicely now.

Comment: Given your handle of 'Learner' and rep of 20, I just wanted to offer a caution about using `It.IsAny` in case you don't know. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332471/mock-verify-invocation)'s not accepted answer and comments, then the accepted answer.