# Mock Verify() Invocation

Tags: c#, mocking, xunit

I'm unit testing to see if a method is called.

```
[Fact]
        public void Can_Save_Project_Changes()
        {
            //Arrange
            var user = new AppUser() { UserName = "JohnDoe", Id = "1" };
            Mock<IRepository> mockRepo = new Mock<IRepository>();
            Mock<UserManager<AppUser>> userMgr = GetMockUserManager();
            userMgr.Setup(x => x.FindByNameAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(new AppUser() { UserName = "JohnDoe", Id = "1" });
            var contextUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
            }));
            Mock<ITempDataDictionary> tempData = new Mock<ITempDataDictionary>();
            ProjectController controller = new ProjectController(mockRepo.Object, userMgr.Object)
            {
                TempData = tempData.Object,
                ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
                {
                    HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() { User = contextUser }
                }
            };

            Project project = new Project()
            {
                Name = "Test",
                UserID = "1",
            };

            //Act
            Task<IActionResult> result = controller.EditProject(project);

            //Assert

            mockRepo.Setup(m => m.SaveProject(It.IsAny<Project>(), user));
            //This line still throws an error
            mockRepo.Verify(m => m.SaveProject(It.IsAny<Project>(), user));
            Assert.IsType<Task<IActionResult>>(result);
            var view = result.Result as ViewResult;
            Assert.Equal("ProjectCharts", view.ViewName);
            Assert.Equal("Project", view.Model.ToString());
        }
```

While debugging, I can verify that the method is actually called in the controller,

```
//This controller line is touched walking through the code
repository.SaveProject(project, user);

//but this repo line is not touched
public void SaveProject(Project project, AppUser user)
```

Debugging doesn't actually show entrance into the repository method. The exact error is below

> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: m => m.SaveProject(, JohnDoe)
>
> No setups configured.
>   Performed invocations:
>   IRepository.ProjectClass
>   IRepository.SaveProjects(ProjectClass, JohnDoe)'

When I do an actual integration test, the `SaveProject` method is touched in the repository and seems to work properly. I've also tried assigning every `Project` property within the unit test but got the same error result

Comment: You need to share the code of unit tests. And the code which you are unit testing. Only bits and pieces won't help

Comment: If the `project` and `user` are not the exact objects as in the verify, then your test will fail and give that exception

Comment: @CodingYoshi Based on the `Performed invocations` message, you have the right answer, so why are you posting it as a comment rather than an answer? If the OP accepts your answer it will prevent people wasting time coming to offer an answer to a solved question.

Comment: This is why _mocking_ is a dangerous ridiculous religion.  https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2016/05/25/have-you-unit-tested-that-aileron-servo/

Comment: Don't throw the baby out with the bathwater, @MickyD. Just because in some situations mocking isn't a great idea, doesn't mean it's never valuable. When I test my data layer, I do it as you said: as an integration test, with no mocking; because mocking the database takes a fair effort, and the likelihood is that you mock it incorrectly, invalidating your tests. However, I use Mocking for *all* the other layers of my application, because otherwise the cost of writing **and maintaining** integration tests is exponentially higher. If you don't want that tool in your toolbelt, that's up to you.

Comment: I see that fbastian's answer has been accepted. Just to say that your second parameter was correct in your original attempt, so doesn't need the `It.IsAny` (which will weaken your test). If you want to post the text of your test, I could probably explain to you what the problem was with the first parameter; otherwise, you're going to end up using `It.IsAny` for everything (& let me know if you do this).

Comment: @Richardissimo I was too quick to accept his answer, but appreciate all the discussion. I have added code to help clarify the situation

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the good discussion, I've learned a lot. @Richardissimo found the issue with the `userMgr.Setup()` method. In response to @MickyD shared link, while I agree that unit testing should not be an end-all/be-all of testing, the analogy in the link may be slightly flawed. In this case, I wasn't testing speed of the system but merely that the right component interactions were occurring. As stated elsewhere, unit testing is just one tool in the toolbox

Comment: @Richardissimo enjoy debugging your overly-convoluted unit tests. The **only** thing mocking does is to allow unit tests to run quicker whilst providing you with a false sense of accomplishment.   It simply moves in-house bugs to field defects.   Be prepared to explain your philosophy to the product manager.  Good luck

Comment: @coolhand your unit testing is now rather risky.  Besides, your mocking is now as complex as the AUT itself. This is the second SO question in so many days where mocking had unexpected behaviour or required a ridiculous level of comprehension.  To you fans of mocking, do you have unit tests for your mock tests or are you happy enough with the green lights in your CI dashboard?   Didn’t think so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to go a step further than Yoshi's comment.

The `Performed invocations` message tells you the method was called but not with the parameters that you were verifying. My guess based on the messages is that there's something wrong with the first parameter.

You would need to post the test for me to be able to be more specific.

**Update (after the Test was added)**

Change `userMgr.Setup` to return your 'user' variable, not a duplicate. Despite what I said earlier, this was the cause of your failure - the code being tested was being given a duplicate, and Moq was correctly saying that your method had not been called with `user` because it had been called with the duplicate. So changing it to this fixes the problem:

```
userMgr.Setup(x => x.FindByNameAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(user);
```

This could be made even stronger if the use of `It.IsAny<string>()` can be avoided: if the specific string that is expected as a parameter is set up as part of the test setup, then give the value instead.

I suspect both of the "1" strings need to be identical to make this work, so rather than duplicate the string declare a local variable and use that instead of both strings.

I would suggest never using values like 1; prefer to randomly type something, so that it doesn't coincidentally pass. By which I mean, imagine a method which takes two integers as parameters: when calling Setup or Verify for that method, if you use the same value for both those integers, the test could pass even if your code has mistakenly swapped the values over (passing each into the wrong parameter). If you use different values when calling Setup or Verify, then it will only work when the correct value is passed in the correct parameter.

`mockRepo.Setup` is redundant. Setup allows you to specify how the class behaves but there is nothing else after that on the line, so its redundant and can be removed. Some people use setup along with VerifyAll but you might want to read this discussion about using [VerifyAll](http://russellallen.info.gridhosted.co.uk/post/2011/04/15/Moq-asserts-Verify()-vs-VerifyAll().aspx).

Now change your verify back to using `project` rather than `It.IsAny<Project>()`. I would expect it to work.

**Update 2**

Consider a tiled roof. Each tile is responsible for protecting one small part of the roof, slightly overlapping the ones below it. That tiled roof is like a collection of unit tests when using mocking.

Each 'tile' represents one test fixture, covering one class in the real code. The 'overlapping' represents the interaction between the class and the things it uses, which has to be defined using mocks, which are tested using things like Setup and Verify (in Moq).

If this mocking is done badly, then the gaps between the tiles will be big, and your roof could leak (i.e. your code might not work). Two examples of how mocking can be done badly:

1. Not checking the parameters which are given to the dependencies, by using `It.IsAny` when you really don't need to.
2. Incorrectly defining the behaviour of the mock compared to how the real dependency would behave.

That last one is your biggest risk; but it's no different than the risk of writing bad unit tests (regardless of whether it involves mocking). If I wrote a unit test which exercised the code under test but then failed to make any assertions, or made an assertion about something that doesn't matter, that would be a weak test. Using `It.IsAny` is like saying "I don't care what this value is", and means you're missing the opportunity to assert what that value *should* be.

There are times when it's not possible to specify the value, where you have to use `It.IsAny`, and one other case I'll come back to in a second is also OK. Otherwise, you should always try to specify what the parameters are, either exactly, or at least using `It.Is<T>(comparison lambda)`. The one other time it's ok to use `It.IsAny<T>()` is when you are verifying that a call has *not* been made, using `Times.Never` as a parameter to `Verify`. In this case, it is usually a good idea to always use it, since it checks the call has not been made with any parameter (avoiding the possibility that you have simply made an error on what parameters are given).

If I wrote some unit tests which gave me 100% code coverage; but didn't test all the possible scenarios, that would be weak unit testing. Do I have any tests to try to find these badly written tests? No, and people who don't use mocking don't have tests like that either.

Going back to the tiled roof analogy... if I didn't have mocking, and had to test each part using the real dependencies here's what my roof would look like. I could have a tile for all of the bits at the bottom edge of the roof. No problem so far. For what would have been the next set of tiles up the roof, for what would have been one tile, I need a triangular tile, covering where that tile would have gone, and covering the tiles below it (even though they are already covered by a tile). Still, not too bad. But 15 tiles further up the roof, this is going to get exhausting.

Bringing that to a real world scenario, imagine I'm testing a client-side piece of code, which uses two WCF services, one of which is a third party that charges per use, one of which is protected by windows authentication, maybe one of those services has complex logic in its business layer before reaching the data layer and interacting with a database, and somewhere in there, I might have some caching. I daresay writing decent tests for this without mocking could be described as overly-convoluted, if it's even possible (in one person's lifetime)...

Unless you use mocking, which allows you to...

1. Test your code that depends on the third-party code, without making calls into it (acknowledging the risks mentioned earlier about mocking that accurately).
2. Simulate what would happened if a user with or without the right permissions called the protected WCF service (think about how you would do that from automated tests without mocking)
3. Test separate parts of code in isolation, which is particularly valuable where complex business logic is involved. This exponentially reduces the number of paths through the code that need to be tested, reducing the cost of writing the tests, and of maintaining them. Imagine the complexity of having to set up the database with all the prerequisites, not just for the data layer tests, but for all of the tests up the call stack. Now what happens when there is a database change?
4. Test caching by Verifying how many times your mock's method was called.

(For the record, speed of execution of the tests has never played any part in my decision to use mocking.)

Luckily mocking is simple, requiring barely any level of comprehension above what I have spelled out here. As long as you acknowledge that using mocking is a compromise compared to full-on integration testing, it yields the kind of savings in development and maintenance time that any product manager will be grateful for. So try to keep the gaps between your tiles small.

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you on the advice for setting values as well, that wasn't anywhere on my radar

Comment: Thank you again for the detailed explanation. Your analogy makes sense and has helped me write stronger tests, especially in the cases where I'm checking that a method is not touched

Answer (score 1):

Try to setup your method like this:

mockRepo.Setup(m => m.SaveProject(It.IsAny(),It.IsAny())

And then verify using It.IsAny as well.

Or just use It.IsAny for the parameters you do not want (or cannot) check properly for some reason. You can also create custom matchers in the later case.

As mentioned in other comments. The problem is likely to be on the arguments that you have setup you mock to expect.

Comment: Just to point out that using It.IsAny<T>() weakens yous tests. There are times when it's **not possible** to specify the value, which is fine, and one other case I'll come back to in a second. Otherwise, you should always try to specify what the parameters are, either exactly, or at least using It.Is<T>(comparison lambda). The one other time it's ok to use It.IsAny<T>() is when you are verifying that a call has not been made, using `Times.Never` as a parameter to Verify. In this case, it is usually a good idea to **always** use it since it checks the call has not been made with any parameter.

Comment: It does not necessarily weakens the test. It all depends on the purpose of the test. Sometimes, for example, you just want to test how many times a function was called (or that it has been called at all). In this case the arguments which the function has been called with are not what you want to test.

Comment: By definition, it *does* weaken the test: it means "I don't care what this parameter is". A Setup/Verify that does not specify what parameters are expected when calling a dependency isn't testing that the code under test is behaving correctly. For example, if the two parameters were 'int's and the code under test passed the parameters in the wrong order, a test using 2 `It.IsAny<int>()` would pass, but the code would not work. This is the kind of scenario which convinces people that mocking is the problem; when really it's just bad use of mocking. As I've said, sometimes it's not possible.

Comment: I don't agree. You have to know what you want to test. If the parameters which a certain mock function is called with are important for a particular test, then of course you are right. But there are cases  (as the one I mentioned) where the parameters are irrelevant, and you don't want the test to fail if the parameters which a certain mock function are called with change.

Comment: Your examples were 'you just want to test how many times a function was called' which I'd suggest needs the word *correctly*' on the end (because otherwise, why do you care how often it's called). The second example was 'or that it has been called at all', which is the same as the first example. It is critical to understand that mocking is a compromise compared to full integration testing. Without specifying how the mocked dependencies are being used, you are going to get tests which pass and code which fails. 'If the parameters...are important': if they're not *important*, why are they there?

Comment: A unit test has a specific purpose, which can be to verify, for example, that given a certain event or a certain function call, then a certain function (from a dependency) will be executed the correct number of times (or never). I'm not saying that the parameters are not important at all, but just that you will not necessarily test both things in the same unit test. I rest my case here :-)

Comment: I may have been premature in accepting this answer. Maybe it will end up leading me to the right understanding as I'm new to unit testing but the discussion has been very helpful. I've edited the original question to add code.

Comment: Just adding this comment to avoid confusion for later readers. While this answer helped in terms of spurring conversation, it did not actually fix the issue at hand which is why it is not the accepted answer.