# Moq won't invoke IAuthenticationManager SignIn method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-identity, moq

I am trying to run unit tests for a successfull login by verifying that the AuthenticationManager SignIn method has been called once Here's the error I am getting:

> Message: Test method Portfolio.UnitTest.WebUI.Controllers.LoginControllerTests.Login_Verified_Authenticates_System_User threw exception: 
>   Moq.MockException: 
>   Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: m => m.SignIn(AuthenticationProperties, [ClaimsIdentity])
>
> Configured setups: 
>   m => m.SignIn(AuthenticationProperties, [ClaimsIdentity])
>
> Performed invocations: 
>   IAuthenticationManager.SignIn(AuthenticationProperties, [ClaimsIdentity])

Even the error message seems to be contradicting itself.

My controller class/method:

```
public class LoginController : ProjectBaseController
{
private IAuthenticationManager _authenticationManager;
    public IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _authenticationManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
        set
        {
            _authenticationManager = value;
        }
    }
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(LoginViewModel accountUser)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(accountUser);

        var systemUser = _authenticationService.Verify(accountUser.Email, accountUser.Password);
        if (systemUser == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid email address or password");
            return View(accountUser);
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity
        (
            new[] 
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, systemUser.FullName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, systemUser.Email)
            },
            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            ClaimTypes.Name, 
            ClaimTypes.Role
        );

        // Set roles for authorization attributes used throughout dashboard
        foreach(var role in systemUser.Roles)
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name));
        }

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn
        (
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = true
            }, 
            identity
        );

        return Redirect(accountUser.ReturnUrl);   
    }
```

LoginControllerTests:

```
[TestClass]
public class LoginControllerTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IAuthenticationManager> _mockAuthenticationManager;
    private readonly Mock<IAuthenticationService> _mockAuthenticationService;

    public LoginControllerTests()
    {
        _mockAuthenticationManager = new Mock<IAuthenticationManager>();
        _mockAuthenticationService = new Mock<IAuthenticationService>();
    }

    private LoginController GetLoginControllerInstance()
    {
        var controller = new LoginController(_mockAuthenticationService.Object);
        controller.AuthenticationManager = _mockAuthenticationManager.Object;

        return controller;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Login_Verified_Authenticates_System_User()
    {
        // Arrange
        var viewModel = new LoginViewModel("/")
        {
            Email = "email@test.co.uk",
            Password = "password-test"
        };
        var systemUser = new SystemUser()
        {
            Id = new Random().Next(),
            FirstName = "Joe",
            LastName = "Bloggs",
            Email = viewModel.Email,
            Password = viewModel.Password,
            Roles = new List<Role>()
        };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity
        (
            new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, systemUser.FullName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, systemUser.Email)
            },
            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            ClaimTypes.Name,
            ClaimTypes.Role
        );
        var authenticationProperty = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = true
        };

        var controller = this.GetLoginControllerInstance();
        _mockAuthenticationService.Setup(m => m.Verify(viewModel.Email, viewModel.Password))
            .Returns(systemUser);
        _mockAuthenticationManager.Setup(m => m.SignIn(authenticationProperty, identity));

        // Act
        var result = controller.Index(viewModel);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.IsTrue(controller.ModelState.IsValid);
        _mockAuthenticationService.Verify(m => m.Verify(viewModel.Email, viewModel.Password), Times.Once);
        _mockAuthenticationManager.Verify(m => m.SignIn(authenticationProperty, identity), Times.Once);
    }
}
}
```

Running in deubg the method gets called within the controller just fine but Moq appears to be ignoring it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Those are different instances being used in the method under test and the actual test method. That is why it fails the verify

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock Verify() Invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332471/mock-verify-invocation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nkosi said it in a comment to your question:

In the expression

```
m => m.SignIn(authenticationProperty, identity)
```

the two arguments `authenticationProperty` and `identity` must be "equal" to the two arguments actually passed in (by the System-Under-Test). So does `Equals` return true when you compare?

You can use `It.IsAny<AuthenticationProperties>()` or `It.Is((AuthenticationProperties x) => x.IsPersistent)` or similar, if needed. And analogous for the `ClaimsIdentity`. Then Moq will no longer require `Equals` equality.

Comment: It was that simple! Clearly I'm new to all this. Thanks

Comment: @user3112059 Since you're new to mocking, you may want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332471/mock-verify-invocation) for some discussion over the use of It.IsAny.