# Moq logger & verifying calls fails

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, verify

I've created a mock item for my logger so that I can verify what calls are being made to it; like so:

```
  mock_log.Setup(l => l.InfoFormat(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>()));
  mock_log.Verify(m => m.InfoFormat("1 file(s) found that match criteria."), Times.Exactly(1));
```

I've debugged the code and i KNOW that these logs are defiantly being hit in the code so these should be logged. This is the code that logs that message

```
  _log.InfoFormat("{0} file(s) found that match criteria.", files.Count);
```

and there is only 1 file that gets passed down.

So why when I verify the one call it fails?
 Any suggestions.

Comment: What happens if you remove the Setup call? I think you are setting up Moq to expect 2 calls - the Setup and the Verify. I prefer to use Setup for the exact call and the use moq.VerifyAll() to check that the Setups have been used

Comment: There is no need to call the setup, since you are verifying the call you are interested in. Some people use Setup with VerifyAll,  but from my experience, I agree with RussellAllen that this approach [makes it hard to tell what is being asserted](http://russellallen.info.gridhosted.co.uk/post/2011/04/15/Moq-asserts-Verify()-vs-VerifyAll().aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out it's because the string incapsulation doesn't get put through. Change the verify to

```
 mock_log.Verify(m => m.InfoFormat("{0} file(s) found on Ftp server.", 4), Times.Exactly(1));
```

Comment: As you have worked out you must verify the exact signature of call that was made. Remember the mocking framework has no idea that the method you are mocking would do the equivalent of a string format. All it knows is that a particular signature of method was called with certain parameters. This can get tricky if your code under test is using an extension method, since you must verify the actual call that was made.

Answer (score 0):

In the mock setup you are telling the logger that second parameter is an array, but then you are passing in a count at run time. I suspect that's going to be the problem. Try changing to:

`It.IsAny<object>()`

Another thought, the test you are applying in .Verify looks a little odd. I'm not sure what the Times.Exactly(1) is meant to be doing, if the mock is trying to run verify the resulting format string, you probably just want to pass in 1?

Comment: It probably is a `params object[]` parameter, so it is an array.

Comment: Yes it is a params object[] so the setup is right. it turned out its the EXACT representation of the  call not the extrapolated version.

Comment: Just to add caution about casually using `It.IsAny`. There is a discussion  about its use in the comments and answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332471/mock-verify-invocation) which the OP found helpful. Also the tip that you can use `Times.Once` rather than `Times.Exactly(1)`.