# Verify function parameters being called have a specific value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, moq

Basically I have a function

```
public Task CustomerUpdate(string user, JObject jobject)
{
   ...
   JObject newDocument = JObject.FromObject(jobject);
   newDocument["lastUpdate"] = Datetime.Utcnow();
   newDocument["someFlag"] = "foo";
   // change some more properties in newDocument

   // call the database provider
   await this.dbProvider.ReplaceAsync(user, newDocument);
}
```

In my unit test, I'm mocking like this:

```
dbProvider.Setup(p => p.ReplaceAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<JObject>()))
                .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

I need to verify that newDocument being passed as a parameter to dbProvider.ReplaceAsync method have the right property values.

Ideally I want to do this from my unit test:

```
Assert.IsEquals("foo", newDocument["someFlag"])
```

But my unit test does not have access to local variable inside CustomerUpdate function. And i think i cannot use callback either because the dbprovider isn't returning the updated object.

Any idea what can I do?

Comment: You can throw an exception if the parsing was incorrect. You could return the result of `ReplaceAsync` or the object it saves then verify that. But maybe you need to break this procedure up so you can test each stage separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this at the end of your test, which will verify whether it was called with a second parameter containing the value you wanted...

```
dbProvider.Verify(p => p.ReplaceAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.Is<JObject>(j=>j["someFlag"] == "foo")));
```

While I'm here, I'm going to suggest caution about casual use of `It.IsAny`. There is a discussion in the comments and answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332471/mock-verify-invocation) which the OP found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Callbacks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks) for this.

```
JObject updatedDocument= null;
dbProvider.Setup(p => p.ReplaceAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<JObject>()))
            .Returns(Task.CompletedTask)
            .Callback<string, JObject>((u, doc) => updatedDocument = doc);
```

Then use `updatedDocument`for assert.

```
Assert.IsEquals("foo", updatedDocument["someFlag"])
```