# Moq and Entity Framework Core do not really work with asynchronous methods?

Tags: c#, mocking, .net-core, entity-framework-core, moq

I'm trying to create a test repository using Moq with EF Core, using its asynchronous methods (like `AddAsync` and `SaveChangesAsync`), but I have not had the slightest success ...

I've found many and many blog posts (including questions here), but nothing works for me.

For example, I literally copied the code from this article and tried to implement its references: [https://fpnotebook.wordpress.com/2017/05/29/asp-net-core-testing-repositories-and-mocking-ef /] but the problem is always the same, for example:

> Message: Moq.MockException:
>   Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: m => m.AddAsync (It.IsAny  (),)
>   No setups configured.

And the same goes for `SaveChangesAsync`.

Here's an example code I've been trying to implement:

//The configuration

```
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.AddAsync(It.IsAny<T>), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .Callback ((T model, CancellationToken token) => {queryableList.Concat (new [] {model})}})
    .Returns ((T model, CancellationToken token) => Task.FromResult((EntityEntry<T>) null));
```

// The test itself

```
[Fact]
public async void AddAsyncTest ()
{
    var mockSet = new Mock <DbSet <Wine >> ();

    var mockContext = new Mock <SQLContext> (_ options);
    mockContext.Setup (m => m.Set <Wine> ()). Returns (mockSet.Object);

    var service = new WineCommandRepository (mockContext.Object);
    await service.Insert (new Wine
    {
        IdWine = 1,
        Name = "Wine1"
    });
    mockContext.Object.SaveChanges ();

    mockSet.Verify (m => m.AddAsync (It.IsAny <Wine>), 
        new CancellationToken ()), Times.Once ());

    mockContext.Verify (m => m.SaveChanges (), Times.Once ());
}
```

There is nothing extraordinary about my code, I have used what I have always used for synchronous repository but this case is new to me.

Has anyone overcome this and have some example or recommendation to share?

Comment: Show the code under test and how you access the DbSet

Comment: Avoid using Mocks for DbContext/DbSet (or other EF types). It is likely to cause issues than work. Rather use InMemory provider or SQLite inmemory database for testing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/

Comment: "Avoid using Mocks for DbContext/DbSet (or other EF types)." So what do you suggest?

Comment: I'm using InMemory for tests

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason this isn't working is that this check (for which I have added missing brackets from the question and removed unnecessary brackets) will never pass:

```
mockSet.Verify(m => m.AddAsync(It.IsAny<Wine>()), new CancellationToken()), Times.Once);
```

The reason is that `Verify` is checking that the method was called with the supplied parameters, not something 'equivalent', but exactly what you told it (reference equals). However, the `Verify` is being given a new instance of a CancellationToken, and there is *no possible way* that the code under test will be returning that exact instance of a CancellationToken.

Either you need to use `It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()`, or if you abstract your code under test away from explicitly using `new CancellationToken()`, and supply that via the test setup, then you could supply that specific instance to `Verify`.

While I'm here, I should offer a caution about using `It.IsAny` in case you don't know. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332471/mock-verify-invocation)'s not accepted answer and comments, then the accepted answer.

Comment: Unfortunately for my problem, no. I had to deal with other things at the moment but soon I will resume this task and report the progress.