# To check if List<T> returns a collection using Moq. Guidance needed on how to assert?

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I am trying to use Moq for testing a manager that has many CRUD operations defined in it. One of the methods is taking an integer parameter and returning a list based on conditions. I want to assert if the list does have a count greater than 0. How to do this using Moq? This is my attempt, guidance needed.

```
// set up the mock method making sure integer is passed and list is returned
var mockAssessmentManager = new Mock<IAssessmentManager>();
mockAssessmentManager.Setup(x => x.GetAssessmentElementUserRowByAssessment(It.IsAny<int>()))
                                      .Returns(new List<AssessmentElementUser>());
// Assert.IsTrue(myReturnList.Count > 0);   //want to achieve some like this.

Assert.IsTrue(mockAssessmentManager);
```

Am I doing it the right way? How to assert my collection of `List<T>` to check if count > 0?

Answer (score 0):

The title "To check if `List<T>` returns a collection" makes no sense because `List<T>` is a type not a method, so it doesn't *return* anything it *is* something.

You say you are testing a manager, and the example shows code which is mocking a manager. But if you are mocking the manager, you aren't testing it, you should be testing the thing which uses the manager. I'm going to assume that to be the case.

Given that you are setting up your mock to return a collection when the manager is called, you can use Verify to check that that happened to your mock (the syntax is very similar to Setup). But quite often you don't need to, since the return value from code under test is often driven by the value returned by the dependency.

For example, if the return value from the code under test should be the value that the manager returned to it (which is the collection you return in the Setup), asserting that the value returned is reference equals the same as your mock returned is the solution. (There is no other way that assert could pass unless the method that was setup was called.)

There certainly doesn't seem to be any value in asserting anything about a collection which you have set up as part of your test.

Bonus tip: you haven't tagged which testing framework you're using but `Assert.IsTrue(myReturnList.Count > 0);` is a bad way is asserting, since if the assert fails the message is always "expected true but was false". Whereas `Assert.That(myReturnList, Has.Count.GreaterThan(0));` (I'm assuming NUnit) will give much better information if it fails.

Another tip, I need to offer a caution about using `It.IsAny`. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332471/mock-verify-invocation) (which is about Verify, but the syntax is very similar to Setup, and the concern about It.IsAny is the same). Read the non accepted answer and all the comments, then the accepted answer.