# Async mocked method always returns null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

I am mocking an async method where an interface is the parameter and I want to return a specific object.  It appears that the method call is not being associated with the mock and is therefore always returning null.

Method being mocked:

```
public async Task<IDetail> Create(IDetail detail)
```

n async Mock Statement:

```
IDetail detailCreateResult = new Detail() {...}

mockDetailRespository.Setup(x => x.Create(It.IsAny<IDetail>())).ReturnsAsync(detailCreateResult);
```

Call to the method:

```
var incomeTaxDetail = _detailMapper.Mapper.Map<IDetail> (incomeTaxDetailModel);  // Returns an IDetail
var newDetail = await _detailRespository.Create(incomeTaxDetail);
```

**newDetail is always set to a null value, not to detailCreateResult.**

This mock, used another test, works fine:

```
mockDetailRespository.Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<int>())).ReturnsAsync(detail);
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  If more information is needed please let me know.

Comment: With the code broken up as it is, There is no way to see what the problem is. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. Would save a lot of time trying to figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: Thanks, first time posting here.  I'll try to come up with something.

Comment: You are using `_detailRepository` instead of your mock - `mockDetailRepository.Object`

Comment: (First, sorry for the screwy format of the code, not sure how to show it as code in a reply).  Crowcoder - Thanks.  ALMOST correct.  What I didn't show (and noticed while starting to do as Nkosi asked) was that I was NOT using  my mocked controller!

            var controller = new DetailsController(_mockLoggingRepository, _detailMapper, _mockConfiguration, mockDetailRespository.Object);

            // Act
            var result = await _detailsController.CreateDetail(detailModel);

Comment: @NeilW you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50843219/edit) your post and add that info directly to a question

Comment: Just to offer a caution about using `It.IsAny` without understanding the implications: it can allow your tests to pass when the code is faulty. You may like to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332471/mock-verify-invocation). That question is about Verify, but the same argument applies to Setup. Take a look at the answer proposing use of `It.IsAny` (including all the comments) then the accepted answer.

Comment: @Richardissimo I'll take a look at that.  Thanks.