# trouble debugging async Task in unit test because it's not entered

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

So I am trying to test a method of type async Task that is called inside of a command handler, inside that method I have some ifs and I want to check on which branch it goes.
Because on each branch a certain method is called, I can see which branch it went to by

```
await myRepository.Received(1).Method1(3, null);

Imagine the key method is like this:
public async Task MyKeyMethod(int x) {
if (x == 21) 
      Method1("bla");
if (x == 22)
      Method2("blue");
if (x == 23)
       Method3("ba");
}
```

So I want to test that the call MyKeyMethod(2) actually goes into the branch that calls  Method2("blue");
And I know that I can do this by something like:
await MyKeyMethod.Received(1).Method2(22); // Received(1) means that method was invoked once.

Question 1: what should 22 be? The parameter supplied to Method2 or the one supplied to MyKeyMethod?

Question2: Why does my code not even enter any async Task method that I have inside the command handler (during debugging)? 
Is there any concrete example that you have?

I am able to enter step by step the command by doing something like:

```
var cmd = new MyCommand(myObject); // myObject is an object that I mocked earlier (gave it some dummy values for each field)
var commandResponse = await handler.Handle(cmd);
Assert.That(commandResponse.IsSuccessful, Is.True);
```

...just NOT at the next deeper level, like the async Tasks inside those commands. I can just at the moment simulate what the async Task return, which is not what I want in this instance.

Question 3. Could this be because those async Task methods are inside a repository that is mocked by using

```
myRepository = Substitute.For<IMyRepository>();
```

Question 4. How do I enter actually not mockingly Task methods found inside Repositories that are mocked?

Answer (score 0):

I am still getting the hang of it, "it" being the broader subject of unit tests in NUnit, but apparently my hunch was right. Because the repository was mocked, I could not enter and debug inside of one of its contained methods. So I used a real (not fake) method of the repository which by the way took in its constructors some fake instances of other dependant repos or services, and then I could go inside that Task. 
So, factually, instead of:

```
myRepository = Substitute.For<IMyRepository>();
```

I went and created a real instance, such as:

```
var myRepository = new MyRepository>(mockService1, mockRepo2);
```

where mockService1 was mocked using Substitute like previously pointed out.

And by doing so I could then debug a method like:
`myRepository.MyMethod(x)` which previously the debugger couldn't analyse the inside of.

If you have a better way of phrasing my conclusions, by all means, or more complete explanation, please go ahead. Thank you

Comment: I'd like to try to help. Does `myRepository.MyMethod(x)` equate to `Method2("blue");` in the question? You need to view this question from the perspective of someone who has nothing else but what you've put in the question, and ask yourself how anyone in the world could have answered this question. For future reference It's best if you can provide a [mcve].  *"Because the repository was mocked, I could not enter and debug inside of one of its contained methods"* - that's the point. There are no insides. It's a mock, which will do whatever you have set it up to do, and nothing else.

Comment: You should be focusing on testing the class which is using the mocked object. The way that the mocked dependency behaves is defined by you, allowing your tests to be isolated from how the concrete implementation actually works. You haven't added the tag for the mocking framework you're using to the question; but whatever it is, it should have some way of verifying that a call way made. Maybe it will help for you to read the "tiled roof" analogy I gave in answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332471/mock-verify-invocation) (even though question is for Moq).